# PHP: Saving multiline string as single line in order to save to form using str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I try to save to a txt form a multiline str and then access in using gets function so I try to replace all the \n with something else (#n as an example).
It doesn't work for some reason.
Even when I test the str_replace function on different search terms it doesn't seem to function.
any idea why?

```
<?php
        //define variables
        $docRoot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $author = $_POST["author"];
        $content = $_POST["content"];
        $date = time();

        //building post
        str_replace("\\n", "#n", $content);
        $post = $date.' \t '.$title.' \t '.$author.' \t '.$content."\n";

        //open and writing posts file
        file_put_contents("$docRoot/ToDoProject/posts/posts.txt", $post, FILE_APPEND);

        echo "<h1>Post uploaded!</h1>"
    ?>
```

Post takes data from:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="php/processpost.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Submit post</legend>

    <!--Date -->
    <?php
        $date = date("H:i, dS F, Y");
        echo "$date";
    ?>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author">Author</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="hephaestus" class="form-control input-md" required="">

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="content">Content</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--Submit Button -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit Order" style="position: absolute; right: 2px;">
    Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

also, when do i use str_replace and when prag_replace?
how do I type the same code in prag_replace?

Comment: Try replacing `"\\n"` by `"\n"`.

Comment: tried and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
//building post
str_replace("\\n", "#n", $content);
```

You replace the newline chars with #n, but you do not save the result back to $content. Try this:

```
$content = str_replace("\\n", "#n", $content);
```